# Distribute BigQueryML job (for Cloud Natural Language API) to respect quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created a BigQuery query that runs a ML transformation using GCP's Cloud Natural Language API.

```
    SELECT
      id, 
      text_content,
      ml_understand_text_result,
      FLOAT64(
        ml_understand_text_result.document_sentiment.score
      ) AS score,
      FLOAT64(
        ml_understand_text_result.document_sentiment.magnitude
      ) AS magnitude,
    FROM
      ML.UNDERSTAND_TEXT(
        MODEL `{PROJECT_ID}.{DATASET_ID}.{NLP_MODEL_NAME}`,
          (
            SELECT id
              , content as text_content
            FROM table_a 
          ),
        STRUCT("analyze_sentiment" AS nlu_option)) ;
```

table_a has 600000 rows. However, quota for Cloud Natural Language API is only 600 requests/min.

Hence, the ML transformation results in too many "429" errors (Too many requests).

[image: Graph of API request response codes (429 is dark pink)]

Is there a way to distribute the job? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

600,000 rows exceed the max allowed rows per query for ML.UNDERSTAND_TEXT.
See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#cloud_ai_service_functions for the configured quotas
ML.UNDERSTAND_TEXT is already doing rate limitings but with limited retries.
For a better result, you may try:

1. Split the source data and input into 6 tables to make each less than 100k and run it again.
2. Request a higher rate quota for the NLP service. See https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/quotas for more details.